# Partition GIST index?

Tags: postgresql

I have a partitioned table (by `tree_id`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE tree_people (
    tree_id urn NOT NULL REFERENCES trees(id),
    id urn NOT NULL,
    first_name text,
    CONSTRAINT tree_people_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tree_id, id)
)
PARTITION BY HASH(tree_id);

CREATE TABLE tree_people_1 PARTITION OF tree_people FOR VALUES WITH
  (MODULUS 2, REMAINDER 0);

CREATE TABLE tree_people_2 PARTITION OF tree_people FOR VALUES WITH
  (MODULUS 2, REMAINDER 1);
```

I want to create a GiST index for trigram search on the `name` column:

```sql
CREATE INDEX tree_people_first_name_gist_index ON tree_people
    USING gist(first_name gist_trgm_ops(siglen=256));
```

However when adding the partition key to the query, the index is not being used (seq scan is used instead of index scan):

```sql
WITH input AS (select 'john' as q)
SELECT first_name
FROM tree_people, input
 where tree_id = 'urn:tree:1ff801ae-0579-4ced-992d-cd08e299be85'
AND input.q <% (first_name);
```

The output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` with the `tree_id` is:

```
Seq Scan on tree_people_1 tree_people  (cost=0.00..1.58 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.052..0.477 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (('john'::text <% first_name) AND ((tree_id)::text = 'urn:tree:1ff801ae-0579-4ced-992d-cd08e299be85'::text))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 38
```

The output without using `tree_id`:

```
Append  (cost=4.16..87.06 rows=19 width=32) (actual time=0.070..0.442 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tree_people_0 tree_people_1  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ('john'::text <% first_name)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tree_people_0_first_name_idx  (cost=0.00..4.15 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (first_name %> 'john'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tree_people_1 tree_people_2  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ('john'::text <% first_name)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tree_people_1_first_name_idx  (cost=0.00..4.15 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (first_name %> 'john'::text)
```

I'm using Postgres 13.3

What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure that the index is also partitioned by `tree_id`, just like the table itself?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the version of PostgreSQL you are using and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` for your query to your question. A brief test here shows the index(es) being used with your query with a small amount of test data.

Comment: @dwhitemv I've updated my question with the details. Thank you!

Comment: What is the definition of your custom type `urn`? Your problem seems that it won’t use the PK index for Tree_id. Your Gist index is working fine. Please check that the table definition is correct, I edited it so it worked, but it might not reflect your actual table.

Comment: There is little point in using an index for a table with 39 rows.

Comment: @jjanes that obviously is just dev environment

Comment: OK, but your dev environment is obviously unsuitable for any meaningful performance testing.  Run your test on a non-ridiculous subset of your data.

Comment: @jjanes you were right, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! It turns out that Postgres was choosing not to use the index because a seq scan ended up being cheaper for a small amount of data. Adding a 1000 more rows fixed the issue!